# Project texture on moving object

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

Lets say I'm looking at my scene through a camera. I can project an image sequence onto an object from camera view. I can then move the object, which keeps the image sequence in the same position on the object.

What I'd like to do is bake an image sequence onto an object as though it were being projected from a film projector (not using actual light rays). After the textures have been baked, I want to be able to remove the "source", and have the textures remain in position by virtue of having been baked on.

Anyone know how to do this?

I could do it frame by frame using AnimAll, I think. But it would be nice if there were a faster way.

**Edit**

Here's a GIF. I projected a video clip onto a plane and a sphere. I then moved the sphere. You can see some stretching as it moves because you're starting to see the side. I'd like to first animate the projection so that the sphere's UV's change with each frame. Then I'd like to distort the geometry with shape keys to distort the image.

[image]

Comment: Try the UV project modifier. https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html

Comment: Can you please write an answer to your own question and share what you did? Others with the same question can learn from your experience.

Comment: Shoot. It actually has the same problem. See, as long as the modifier is active, it follows. (I set the camera as the projector) However, shape keys don't distort the image. Also, if I apply the modifier, the UV's are stuck to whatever position they were in on the frame I applied it on.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I'll need to write my own plugin.

Comment: Yep. I think I can do it with Python. I'll let y'all know when it's done.